# Equivalent of Rake Routes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In `RubyOnRails` I could say bundle exec rake routes and it was showing me all the generate routes, their verbs, the controller and action methods they hit, etc.. all in one nice report .
Is there something similar for that in `ASP.NET MVC 5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive used route debugger in the past and it works pretty well.

[Heres a great article on it](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) and [heres a link to the nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/)

Hope this helps